# Convert string data to struct data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a string of the form: `{'text':'abc'},{'text':'def'}` I need to get an array of the form `['abc','def']`

I use the following code: `schema = StructType([StructField('text_str', StringType(), True)]) dsdf.withColumn('text', from_json(col('text'), schema)).show(truncate=False)`

Which returns `['abc']`. How to get what I really need?

Answer (score 0):

```
dsdf.select( \
 expr( \
   "transform( split(language,','), x -> from_json(x,'text String'))" \
 ).alias("text")\
).show()
```

I'm using expr to make a sql string to run `transform` this has the widest compatibility for versions of spark, but `transform` can be run natively in recent versions of pyspark.

`split` will produce an array based off the assumption you can split them by ','

`transform` will operate on each item in an array

`from_json` as you know parses json.